# Explain ungroup() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

If I'm working with a dataset and I want to group the data (i.e. by `country`), compute a summary statistic (`mean()`) and then `ungroup()` the `data.frame` to have a dataset with the original dimensions (`country`-`year`) and a new column that lists the mean for each country (repeated over n years), how would I do that with `dplyr`?  The `ungroup()` function doesn't return a `data.frame` with the original dimensions:

```
gapminder %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    summarize(mn = mean(pop)) %>%
    ungroup() # returns data.frame with nrows == length(unique(gapminder$country))
```

Answer (score 38):

`ungroup()` is useful if you want to do something like

```
gapminder %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(mn = pop/mean(pop)) %>%
ungroup()
```

where you want to do some sort of transformation that uses an entire group's statistics. In the above example, `mn` is the ratio of a population to the group's average population. When it is ungrouped, any further mutations called on it would not use the grouping for aggregate statistics.

`summarize` automatically reduces the dimensions, and there's no way to get that back. Perhaps you wanted to do

```
gapminder %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(mn = mean(pop)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Which creates `mn` as the mean for each group, replicated for each row within that group.

Answer (score 18):

The `summarize()` reduced the number of rows. If you didn't want to change the number of rows, then use `mutate()` rather than `summarize()`.

Answer (score 1):

actually `ungroup()` is not needed in your case.

```
gapminder %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(mn = pop/mean(pop))
```

generates the same results as the following:

```
gapminder %>%
group_by(country) %>%
mutate(mn = pop/mean(pop)) %>%
ungroup()
```

The only difference is that the latter actually runs a bit slower.

Comment: in the question above, `ungroup()` is not needed because the call to `summarize()` already removes the grouping; in your example, omitting `ungroup()` results in a grouped df, which may cause problems later when you run analyses not expecting them to be grouped, so I think it's useful to `ungroup()` after `mutate()` in the general case!