# Why does slice_head return too many rows, specifically more than the 'n' I specified?

Tags: r, dplyr

When making a dataframe of 7 rows I want to return the first row of the dataframe.

```
df <- tibble(
  group = rep(c("b", "c", "a"), c(1, 2, 4)),
  x = runif(7)
)

df
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  group      x
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 b     0.269 
2 c     0.0697
3 c     0.705 
4 a     0.772 
5 a     0.513 
6 a     0.841 
7 a     0.896
```

When I slice, a row per group is returned but I only want one row returned.

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Groups:   group [3]
  group      x
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 a     0.772 
2 b     0.269 
3 c     0.0697
```

How can I return only one row?

Comment: Why would you group first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain ungroup() in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446816/explain-ungroup-in-dplyr)

Comment: I don't know, I had this problem and I forgot I grouped many steps earlier. This is a simplified question and answer.

Comment: I actually think this is a reasonable question and self-answer. I can imagine people having the same problem and this helping them. I have edited the title to help others find it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by ungrouping your dataframe.
Solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_head(n = 1)
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  group     x
  <chr> <dbl>
1 b     0.269
```